# Screen shot upload issues in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I finish all the development of my app and I am trying to update the screen shots as they require.

I take the screen shot in simulator by using `command + s`.
Every time I choose the files to upload, and the iTunes Connect says,

> The dimensions of one or more screenshots are wrong. Learn More.

As you can see in the photo,
[image]

How to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Click on iOS Screenshot properties and you will know.

Comment: @kerry I just figure out the screen shot default resolution is 750 * 1334. How to increase the resolution as the iTunes connect expected, I just don't know how to increase the resolution

Comment: You cannot increase the resolution. Even if you do, the quality will be compromised. Use iPhone 6s plus or iPhone 6 plus to take screenshots

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you are using the simulator to take screenshots. As other people have mentioned you need to use the iPhone 6 Plus simulator to do this.

Also make sure the scale is set to **100%**. You can do this pressing ⌘+1 or go to Window > Scale > 100%.
**The scale of the simulator affects the size of the screenshot.**

Answer (score 1):

Try using an iPhone 6 Plus to take your screenshots. The sizes are there, if you check the  "Learn More".

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to upload the same and exact size of image for which you are uploading.
And make sure you are uploading the screen shot in there respective section.