# new build of iPhone app uploads successfully but iTunesConnect expects iPad screenshots for 12.9” display

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I’m trying to upload the latest build of an iPhone app and am having trouble submitting new screenshots on iTunesConnect. My previous build in November 2017 used Xcode 9.1 and I now run Xcode Version 9.3 (9E145). The current iOS target deployment is 8.0 like my previous build.

iTunesConnect’s Media Manager currently has no problem with previously submitted screenshots but for some unknown reason it expects iPad screenshots for a 12.9” display. Yes I tried creating [new images using iOS6 plus using ⌘+1 to scale to 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44539073/2348597) but Media Manager rejected these images when I tried to drag them into either its iPhone window or its iPad window. I was able to drag the previous set of iPhone images back into the Media Manager iPhone window without issues. But still the Media Manager won’t let me submit the next build.

[image]

The app happens to run on iPad even though it was designed for a device that can be held in one hand. These are the deployment settings.

[image]
So should I switch the device from `Universal` to `iPhone` and upload a new build to iTunesConnect ?

or could there be another reason why Media Manager won’t allow me to submit the latest build ?

e.g. [this report](https://venturebeat.com/2018/02/15/apple-will-require-support-for-iphone-x-screen-ios-11-and-watchos-4-on-april-1/) - about changes to take effect on April Fool's day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This report is officially announced in feb so that every one can made changes and submit their apps accordingly. You can check this news from [here](https://9to5mac.com/2018/02/15/apple-require-new-apps-support-iphone-x/). So its not a April fool.

[Here](https://blog.placeit.net/ios-screenshot-sizes/) is the some image sizes that you have to follow even you got the same image properties from media manager also. Before uploading image make sure size of images is properly matches.

Here I noticed that in `x-code 9.x` , 100% resolution screen shot does not give you that resolution so I take the help of designer. So I suggest you to use photo tool and make a perfect resolution it works properly.

Comment: @Greg I always do with the photoshop and it works for me. I just wanted to say to keep two things in your mind, 1) image size and 2) while changing the size it does not reflect the image quality. Now you can go whatever the editor you have. It always work.

Comment: dahiya, I tried your suggestion and created a 2048 x 2732 iPad screen shot. I'll edit the details into the original question when I know it worked. Your input has been valuable.

Comment: @Greg Your app is universal & previous build is also available for ipad also, now if you turn your app only for iphone than it does not make any sense even you degrading your app(as per my thinking). What is issue right now 1) media does not allow you to upload images for ipad **OR** 2) you unable to upload the build. ?? What is the issue pls specify.

Comment: dahiya, up until 30 minutes ago, my issue was 1) and not 2). However, I managed to create a 2048 x 2732 iPad screen shot which iTunesConnect accepted. So there's a good chance my app can remain universal. It is now awaiting review and I'll make my next move when I know the outcome.

Comment: @Greg I think your prblm has been solved and you r waiting for apple review.

Comment: dahiya, I just realised you've answered my question as it stands. This has to be the accepted answer. Fantastic! I'll edit my question and explain what I did when I know the review outcome.

Answer (score 2):

Change Your device to iPhone then try to upload app on iTunes, As of now you have kept universal so iTunes is assuming your app will also work on iPad too that's why it's asking for a screenshot of iPad also.

Comment: Prahash, that was my initial response too. But looking closely at this report I think we cannot address this by switching from Universal to iPad

Comment: Prakash, out of curiosity I tried uploading a new build after switching from Universal to iPhone (not iPad) but when I tried to submit the app for review the warning persists unfortunately. This eliminates the easy option.

Comment: @Greg can you please check in Assets folder > AppIcon> contain iPad icon too

Comment: Prakash, my assets folder has a lot of iPad icons but no where to place the screenshot 2048 x 2732 that I created following dahiya's suggestion. The time has probably arrived to define my app as something specific to iPhone and not iPad. Would you be willing to continue this discussion off-line ?